# Quebra de linha em uma função

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho uma função em Javascript que mostra um texto em um elemento com um efeito "maquina de escrever", porém queria fazer que este texto venha dentro de uma tag P (Para quebra de linha). Alguém poderia me ajudar? Desde já agradeço.

```
function EE(texto,ClassElemento,tempo){
var char = texto.split('').reverse();
var typer = setInterval(function () {
    if (!char.length) return clearInterval(typer);
    var next = char.pop();
    document.querySelector(ClassElemento).innerHTML += next;
}, tempo);
}
```

Comment: Mas qual é a dúvida exatamente? Você quer colocar quebras de linha no parágrafo e não sabe como?

Comment: A função mostra um texto com efeito em algum seletor, porem a função só lança o texto puro sem nada. Eu queria que vinhe-se dentro de uma tag `P`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira rápida e nem de longe a melhor seria fazendo isso:

```js
function EE(texto,ClassElemento,tempo){
  var char = texto.split('').reverse();
  document.querySelector(ClassElemento).innerHTML = '<p></p>'
  var typer = setInterval(function () {
      if (!char.length) return clearInterval(typer);
      var next = char.pop();
      document.querySelector(ClassElemento).firstChild.innerHTML += next;
  }, tempo);
}

EE('Foo is not bar!', '.foo', 1000)
```

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
```

Comment: Oppaa amigo, deu certinho!

Comment: Muiiiiito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade o `<p>` é para parágrafos, o `<br>`seria para quebras de linha. Mas enfim, vamos ao seu código:

```js
function EE(texto,ClassElemento,tempo){
var char = texto.split('').reverse();
var typer = setInterval(function () {
    if (!char.length) return clearInterval(typer);
    var next = char.pop();
    document.querySelector(ClassElemento).innerHTML += '<br><p>' + next;
}, tempo);
}
```

Coloquei ali na `linha 6` as duas tags `<br><p>` onde ele vai quebrar e dar um parágrafo, mas você pode analisar o que será melhor. E outra, ele está fazendo isso antes de imprimir o caractere, se quiser que seja feita a impressão após faça a inversão:

```js
document.querySelector(ClassElemento).innerHTML += next + '<br><p>';
```

Comment: Deste modelo fica letra por letra em cada linha, assim, eu queria colocar um trecho em cada linha.

Comment: Então peço que reescreva sua pergunta explicando sua necessidade e colocando o máximo de código possível pra podermos te ajudar.